# Uploading file to PHP with shell script

Tags: php, shell, sh, freebsd

Introduction:

I have a running dedicated server and I need to make MySQL backups in every 30min. (/var/db/mysql)

My main dedicated is FreeBSD the other one is CentOS with cPanel.

Question:

Normally I use a FTP shell script to make backups, but you know FTP is not good to make backups, it's old etc. So here I want to make PHP script and, upload my backups to other server with a PHP script, (I'm gonna make an IP restriction and also and some protections)

For example: site.com/parse_backups.php

This script is going to take my tar.gz files and store it somewhere in server where is unreachable.

How can I make that shell script?
Which ways I should you use to make that PHP script..

Or do you have better solution that script only uploads file and can't fetch any file etc...

Comment: I am already using a shell with FTP, but it's not safe..

Answer (score 1):

PHP can be used to scripts as well as any other language.

If you're running a FreeBSD server I would suggest .sh scripts instead but that's just an opinion. PHP can be used as a scripting language.

If I have not completly misunderstood your question I suggest you start here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php